# Including poppler in Qt project results in error

Tags: qt, qt5, poppler

I downloaded the latest version of poppler from [here](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler). I went into the Qt5 folder, copied the src folder, put it next to my other header and source files. According to [this](http://people.freedesktop.org/~aacid/docs/qt5/index.html) page, all i have to do in order to get poppler working is to include poppler-qt5.h. It seems to be including the file allright, however when including the file, i get the error:

[image: Error]

Am i doing something wrong, or is there an error in the source code of poppler?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the problem by adding:

```
DEFINES += NOMINMAX
```

in the .pro file